# My input is always true and infinite loop

Tags: python-3.x

I can't seem to understand while my code will run no matter what is entered. I have it set to 'yes' gives you a certain output and anything like 'no' should give you something else. It also runs on an infinite loop which I'm sure I can fix later somehow. Thanks for any help I am sorry for the probably dumb question.

```
print("the test game")
choice = input("do you want to play? Yes or No?")

choice = "Yes"
while choice == "Yes":
    print("No you don't..")
else:
    print("Yes you do..")
```

Comment: You explicitly throw away the result from `input` and just assign `choice = "Yes"`. Of course it always runs. And you never change `choice` within the loop, so again, of course the loop is infinite. What is confusing you about this?

Comment: Probably you want to call `choice = input(...)` inside the loop too. Or use `if-else`

Comment: did you perhaps confuse `while` with `if`?

Answer (score 0):

So I was looking at your code and I tried to run it on my device and well, an observation to be mentioned first is, that you have defined a variable `choice` as input first and then given it `"yes"` as the value later.

The reason the loops continues to work is that, while loop will work until the input it gets remains the same and as you could see that te input of `choice` is set to `"yes"`, it is not a one time use value but it will run the loop infinitely. The `while` loop requires the value which has been given already so it doesn't need an input from the user. That's that with your infinite loop issue.

And I think, you want the answer to the question why your code doesn't work, well that is also because of that variable `choice` which is nuisance at this point. It discards the user input from above. So well, the choice in the while loop will also work, when you remove

```
choice = "yes"
```

because this is the major statement resenting the ideal flow of the program.

---

I hope I could be of any help, if you need any help do comment as ask me!